# Dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, object, powershell

I'm working on finishing my script, but I'm still missing an essential part. It all started with creating a function to import an Excel sheet and yesterday I've made the function to set the permissions. Now it's time to put them both to work, but that's where I'm struggling.

**Excel sheet 'Permissions':**

```
Folder          | Employees | Plant managers | Plant workers
SHARE           | R         | C              | L
SHARE\Folder 1  | C         | R              | R
SHARE\Folder 2  | L         | R              | L
```

When I import this Excel sheet, I have 2 different `arrays`:

```
$Permissions | Format-Table
Folder:           Employees:  Plant managers:  Plant workers:
SHARE             R           C                L
SHARE\Folder 1    C           R                R
SHARE\Folder 2    L           R                L

$PermissionsReverse | Format-Table
Folder:           SHARE:  SHARE\Folder 1:  SHARE\Folder 2:
Employees         R       C                L
Plant managers    C       R                R
Plant workers     L       R                L
```

I need to find a way to combine them both so I can set the permissions on the correct folders for the correct security group.

The folders and the job descriptions are preceded with some text to generate the full path (UNC) and the SAMaccountName:

```
# SAMaccountName
My Prefix Employees
My Prefix Plant managers
My Prefix Plant workers

# Folder
\\Server1\Share
\\Server1\Share\Folder 1
\\Server1\Share\Folder 2

# R = ReadAndExecute, L = ListContents, C = Modify
```

I've already made a function called `Set-Permissions` that applies permissions to a folder based on the switch `ReadAndExecute, Change or ListContents`. In the end I want to be able to do something like this for each folder/SAMaccountName, but I don't know how to iterate through the arrays:

```
Set-Permissions -Folder "\\Server1\SHARE" -SAMaccountName "My Prefix Employees" -Grant ReadAndExecute
Set-Permissions -Folder "\\Server1\SHARE" -SAMaccountName "My Prefix Plant managers" -Grant Change
Set-Permissions -Folder "\\Server1\SHARE" -SAMaccountName "My Prefix Plant workers" -Grant ListContents
...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've read this about 5 times and I'm really confused... How do you define a prefix for **I need to add a prefix to the job function name to obtain the correct security group name**? What and where is `$GroupName`? Is that part of your object?

Comment: Can you change the CSV? I would change it so that the permissions are the columns, and the values are the list of groups that have those permissions. You'll have to use something other than commas to separate the groups, though.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I've updated the OP and almost rewritten it completely to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not completely clear about your question. Below is a solution that will iterate the csv file and build the command for your "set-permissions" function.

```
function convert-permissions($perms) {
  switch($perms) {
    "R" { return "ReadAndExecute" }
    "C" { return "Modify" }
    "L" { return "ListContents" }
    default { return "ListContents" }
  }
}

$import = import-csv ".\path\to\your.csv"
$colnames = $($import | get-member | ? { $_.membertype -eq 'NoteProperty' }).name
$sharePrefix = "\\server\"

foreach ($row in $import) {
  foreach ($p in $colnames) {
    if ($p -ne 'Folder') { 
      write-host "Set-Permissions -Folder $sharePrefix$($row.folder) -SAMaccountName $p -Grant $(convert-permissions $row.$p)"
    }
  }
}
```

Remove the `write-host` if the output looks correct. I still don't know how you're generating the "prefix" for your groups, so I've omitted. If it's just a static transformation, I suggest passing the names through another function and returning the modified name.

Comment: @DarkLite1 You clearly haven't actually run this if that's your comment! That logic is contained within the `foreach` loops. Run it and look at the output. The rest is there simply for clarity.

Comment: You are absolutely right! That's why I removed my previous comment, as it was incorrect. Still figuring out how it works, so I can come up with this myself next time. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `psobject` property to access object members: `$_.psobject.Properties`

```
# Generating an object akin to what OP describes
$customObject = ""|Select-Object @{N="Group1";E={"R"}},@{N="Group2";E={"C"}},@{N="Group3";E={"L"}},@{N="Folder";E={"S:\Share\Folder"}}
$customObject = $customObject |Select-Object @{N="MyPrefixGroup1";E={$_."Group1"}},@{N="MyPrefixGroup2";E={$_."Group2"}},@{N="MyPrefixGroup3";E={$_."Group3"}},*

# Get the noteproperties with "MyPrefix" prefixes
$permissions = $customObject.psobject.Properties |Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" -and $_.Name -like "MyPrefix*"}

# Go through each one and set the permission
foreach($permission in $permissions)
{
    # Remove "MyPrefix" from the NoteProperty name
    $GroupName = $permission.Name-replace"MyPrefix",""

    switch($permission.Value)
    {
        R { Set-Permissions $GroupName R; break }
        C { Set-Permissions $GroupName C; break }
        L { Set-Permissions $GroupName L; break }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias, but it's not really what i'm looking for. And that's my fault as I wasn't clear enough. I've updated the OP to be more clear, I'm sorry for your trouble.